# Error when spring-servlet.xml tries to autowire beans defined in application-context.xml

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, mybatis

So I'm trying to create a Rest web service with Spring, which will have Controllers that will contact my DB through a MyBatis interface. My Service and Repository beans are autowired in the application-context.xml and my controllers are injected in the spring-servlet.xml. My problem is that when I try to deploy my war on my local tomcat server I get the following error;

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.programme.server.service.TeamService com.programme.server.controller.TeamController.teamService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.programme.server.service.TeamService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.programme.server.service.TeamService com.programme.server.controller.TeamController.teamService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.programme.server.service.TeamService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.programme.server.service.TeamService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1009)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
```

application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.programme.server">
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" 
                   expression="com.programme.server.controller.*Controller.*" />
</context:component-scan>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"> 
        <value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value> 
    </property> 
    <property name="url"> 
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value> 
    </property> 
    <property name="username"> 
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value> 
    </property> 
    <property name="password"> 
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value> 
    </property> 
</bean> 

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.programme.server.domain" />
  <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:/resources/mappers/*.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.programme.server.mapper" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.programme.server.controller" />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>



</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Programme Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml
         </param-value> 
     </context-param>

    <listener>
       <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
       </listener-class>
    </listener> 

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the controller throwing the error...

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.programme.server.domain.Team;
import com.programme.server.service.TeamService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/team")
public class TeamController {

    @Autowired
    private TeamService teamService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Team retrieveTeam(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        return teamService.retrieveTeam(id);
    }
}
```

And here's the service impl...

```
package com.programme.server.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.programme.server.dao.TeamDao;
import com.programme.server.domain.Team;

@Service
public final class TeamServiceImpl implements TeamService {

    @Autowired
    private TeamDao teamDao;

    @Override
    public List<Team> finalAll() {
        return teamDao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Team retrieveTeam(int id) {
        return teamDao.retrieveTeam(id);
    }

}
```

and interface...

```
package com.programme.server.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.programme.server.domain.Team;

public interface TeamService {

    public List<Team> finalAll();

    public Team retrieveTeam(int id);
}
```

The Service layer definitely has the '@Service' annotation and I've tested with a 'main' application and everyting is injected - which leads me to believe the problem lies in the spring-servlet.xml not knowing about the beans injected by the 'application-context.xml'. I'm confused as to why this would be a problem however as I thought that the application-context.xml acted as a 'parent' context for the servlet context. Any help as to what's going wrong here would be great. Do I need to inject everything in the application-context? I've also provided a screenshot of my project hierarchy...

[image: Project Hierarchy]

Comment: For starters cleanup your config. Remove the `<mvc:/>` stuff from the `application-context.xml` add the `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` to the `spring-servlet.xml`. Also remove the `<tx:annotation-driven />` from the `spring-servlet.xml`. Also you are scanning all your web related beans twice, add an exclude filter to the `component-scan` in your `application-context.xml`. And please add the code for the service.

Comment: @M.Deinum- Thanks for the help. So I made the changes you mentioned above and still no change :/ Is there a way of specifically telling the spring-servlet.xml about the application-context.xml beans? I was going to use <import resource/> but this doesn't seem right to me

Comment: No as they are used as a parent. If they cannot be found it isn't instantiated. Looking at your web.xml you don't have anything loading your `application-context.xml`... There is no `ContextLoaderListener` so nothing is going to be loaded in the first place.

Comment: Okay well at least my understanding is correct :) You are right though, I forgot to add the ContextLoaderListener class to web.xml - I assume this is what you are referring to above? I added this and my Tomcat is starting without error now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

So just to close this off...

The fix for me was to add

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```

to my web.xml. I had the context path for applicatiopn-context.xml in here, but I guess I wasn't actually loading it on startup, hence no beans were injected